# How to bind class with Dictionary<string,object> property to datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, .net-3.5

I have a scenario where i have to dynamically fetch the data and store it in a dictionary for display.

This is how my Model looks like:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string,object> CustomFields { get; set; }
}
```

I am binding my view model to DataGrid and i have two columns defined for Id and Name.

How do i generate columns for the data in the dictionary?

I cannot use Dynamic object as i am using .net 3.5.

This is how my XAML looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="MyClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyViewModel"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyModel"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="List Of Projects" Height="600" Width="600">

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:SomeViewModel></viewmodel:SomeViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>

<tk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="dgData" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObjects}"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" >

<tk:DataGrid.Columns>
   <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"  Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True"></tk:DataGridTextColumn>

   <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"></tk:DataGridTextColumn>
</tk:DataGrid.Columns>

</tk:DataGrid>

</Window>
```

Comment: With what you want to bind Dictionary Combobox or any listControl?

Comment: Datagrid. The one that you see in XAML which has two columns (Id and Name). Rest of the columns need to come from the dictionary's Key and value will be Doctionary's Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Converter :

CS :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }


    public Dictionary<int, string> MyDictionary 
    {
        get
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dic.Add(1,"11111");
            dic.Add(2,"22222");
            dic.Add(3,"33333");
            dic.Add(4,"44444");

            return dic;                
        }
    }
}

public class DictionaryConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)values[0];
        IDictionary<int,string> dic = (IDictionary<int,string>)values[1];

        bool isId = bool.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        var index = row.GetIndex();

        KeyValuePair<int,string> kv = dic.ElementAt(index);

        return isId ? kv.Key.ToString() : kv.Value;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <loc:DictionaryConverter x:Key="dicConverter" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dicConverter}" ConverterParameter="True">
                        <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}" />
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>                    
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dicConverter}" ConverterParameter="False">
                        <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}" />
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```